# How to store previous event.currentTarget in a variable

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to store the previous node of the event.currentTarget in a variable to apply some styling to the previous node, and another to the current node but so far I haven't find a way.

Bellow you'll find the code I am trying to write but doesn't seem to store the variable as the previous target

```
questionsArray.map((question) => {
  if (Object.values(question).includes(true) == true) {
    let previousTarget = e.currentTarget
    console.log(previousTarget)
    e.previousTarget.className = "qgroup red";
    e.currentTarget.className = "qgroup blue";
  }
})
```

Comment: Why was this tagged React and JSON? If you are using React, my answer wouldn't make sense and neither would the code in the question--you'd want to take a React-specific approach. So I'm assuming that's out of the picture and those were just mistakes. `Object.values(question).includes(true) == true` is a pretty odd way to use a data structure, so this looks like a potential design flaw. Usually, you perform look ups on objects by key rather than by value.

Comment: Quick nitpick-- `someArray.includes(true)` will return a boolean-- there's no need to compare it to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a variable `previousTarget` doesn't make it so. As is, this is just another name for the `currentTarget`. Move `previousTarget` outside the handler and only assign the `currentTarget` to it at the very end of the handler.

`previousTarget` will be undefined on first click, so be sure to handle that.

```js
let prevTarget = null;

for (const div of [...document.querySelectorAll(".box")]) {
  div.addEventListener("click", event => {
    if (prevTarget) {
      prevTarget.classList.remove("blue");
      prevTarget.classList.add("red");
    }
    
    event.currentTarget.classList.add("blue");
    prevTarget = event.currentTarget;
  });
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

If you want the previous previous to be returned to the default state, you can do that too:

```js
let prevTarget = null;
let prevPrevTarget = null;

for (const div of [...document.querySelectorAll(".box")]) {
  div.addEventListener("click", event => {
    if (prevPrevTarget) {
      prevPrevTarget.classList.remove("red");
    }

    if (prevTarget) {
      prevTarget.classList.remove("blue");
      prevTarget.classList.add("red");
    }
    
    event.currentTarget.classList.add("blue");
    prevPrevTarget = prevTarget;
    prevTarget = event.currentTarget;
  });
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```